# Tracking Android Device

Tags: applications, location-services, gps-tracking

As a common man, we can't track Android devices with a mobile number but all apps cheat us which are available in-app store in name of tracking, tracker, etc… that apps will simply answer state which mobile number belongs too.

We can track an Android phone given constraints that the phone has “find my device” as device administrator ( Most of the times its already is you need to do nothing but you can check at settings>security>device).

Then go here to track location [Sign in - Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone)

For Xiaomi devices, we can go to [Mi Cloud](http://i.mi.com/) for tracking mobile and various other things.

**We are not bothered about the life-saving apps until we lost our Smart Phone or PC. Once something happens badly, we will run behind the apps to track the device.**

> **What do you do if you don’t have any tracking apps installed on your device or your device is not able to communicate with these apps? Is there are any solutions to track your device**

Comment: Short and simple - NO

Comment: @beeshyams any savior recommendations to feed into the existing android devices??

Comment: Sorry, AFAIK, none

Comment: @Pluviophile for my enlightenment, what in your opinion/imagination can possibly be a way to communicate with a lost device which doesn't have a software/framework to respond to your communication request?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Without tracking apps installed on the device. No, I don't know.

Comment: So there is no way to track the device if we lost.

Comment: Apparently, installing a phone tracking app would be the only way? I've read about some services and tools like this one https://www.mspy.com/current-gps-location.html, maybe it would work. Although, there are two sides of the coin actually. Finding a device without additional tools installed would be great, but that can be considered kind of privacy violation, wouldn't it? Like...vback mirror much